# Tomcat 503 Error

Tags: java, tomcat, http-status-code-503

I'm trying to get my site running on a local Tomcat server. However, when I get it running it just returns an HTTP Error 503. I tried increasing the threads and setting `socket_keepalive="true"` but I can't figure out why it's not working.

These are the logs that it returns.

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load THING/env/resource/bundlerService_dev.properties.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
2017-09-18 13:12:44.963 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Reconnecting {QA sa=w1qamc03.web1.PLACE.net/10.50.54.34:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}
2017-09-18 13:12:44.966 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Reconnecting {QA sa=w1qamc02.web1.PLACE.net/10.50.54.33:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}
2017-09-18 13:12:44.970 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Reconnecting {QA sa=w1qamc01.web1.PLACE.net/10.50.54.32:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}
2017-09-18 13:12:44.996 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@14ab43d0
2017-09-18 13:12:45.000 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Reconnecting due to failure to connect to {QA sa=w1qamc01.web1.PLACE.net/10.50.54.32:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}
java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:629)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.handleIO(MemcachedConnection.java:409)
    at net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection.run(MemcachedConnection.java:1334)
2017-09-18 13:12:45.002 WARN net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Closing, and reopening {QA sa=w1qamc01.web1.PLACE.net/10.50.54.32:11211, #Rops=0, #Wops=0, #iq=0, topRop=null, topWop=null, toWrite=0, interested=0}, attempt 37.
2017-09-18 13:12:45.005 INFO net.spy.memcached.MemcachedConnection:  Connection state changed for sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl@12edeb9d
```

After looking through more logs I find this:

```
WARNING: Unknown default host [local.wwe.com] for connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
Sep 18, 2017 1:38:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 18, 2017 1:38:42 PM org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener findDefaultHost
WARNING: Unknown default host [local.wwe.com] for connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
```

I'm not entirely sure what this means.

Any and all help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Check your tomcat logs for earlier error messages. That would tell you why your web app is stopped

Comment: I look through the logs and nothing obvious comes up. It seems to be trying to access memcache even though I don't use memcache in the project. I use ehcache.